# How to configure babel to properly transpile a file with native node requirements?

Tags: node.js, babeljs

I'm using the `@as-integrations/koa` [package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@as-integrations/koa) to create apollo middleware for a koa app.

This works fine, yet the issue occurs when transpiling - The `index.js` file uses `require` statements to import native node modules:

```
const node_stream_1 = require("node:stream");
const node_url_1 = require("node:url");
```

When trying to bundle, I'm getting errors on these imports:

```
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'node:stream'
```

This is the rule set Im using to transpile the file:

```
      {
        test: /\.(ts|mjs|js)$/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        include: /node_modules\/(@as-integrations)\/.*/,
        options: {
          presets: ['@babel/preset-env'],
          plugins: ["@babel/plugin-transform-async-generator-functions"]
        }
      }
```

Seems like I'd need to somehow have babel ignore these require statements, since they will clearly work during runtime.